# java.exe=jvm and javac .exe=compiler

Tags: java

I think

- `java.exe` = JVM
- `javac.exe` = compiler

Is this right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit of a simplification, but mostly yes.

`java.exe` is how you start the JVM. `javac.exe` is how you start the compiler.

The actual implementation of the JVM and compiler doesn't lie within those particular files (only), however.

Comment: can i find the compiler files and jvm files in the jdk

Comment: @saravanan - well yes.  Where else would you expect them to be?

Comment: At least in the Sun JDK, the JVM files are mostly in `jre/lib`, while the compiler is usually found in `tools.jar`.

Comment: @Vladimir Ivanov  :just to know that how those files will be..like all class files we use in rt.jar(in jre)